# What is the extended centroid of a free algebra?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings, localization

For a prime ring $R$, you can define its "*Martindale ring of quotients*" $Q(R)$. See for example:

*Martindale, Wallace S. III*, [**Prime rings satisfying a generalized polynomial identity**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(69)90029-5), J. Algebra 12, 576-584 (1969). [ZBL0175.03102](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0175.03102).

The center of this ring is called the "*extended centroid*" of $R$. It is known that it is a field.

I was wondering if anyone knows what is the extended centroid of $R = K\left<x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\right>$, the free associative algebra over a field $K$? Is it just $K$ in this case?

In the literature (as the title of the article above suggests), this construction is usually considered in the case of rings with a polynomial identity. I cannot find any mention of the construction for free algebras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert, but I think it follows from Theorem 11 and the rest of the discussion in Section 6 of

*Bergman, George M.; Lewin, Jacques*, [**The semigroup of ideals of a fir is (usually) free**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-11.1.21), J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 11, 21-31 (1975). [ZBL0275.16003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0275.16003)

that the extended centroid of $K\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$ is just $K$, as you speculated.

Comment: It looks like you are probably right. Thanks!